# Generating matlab array from two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, matching

I have two large arrays which I will illustrate using the following examples.

The first array A is:

```
[ 1 21;
  3 4;
  4 12;
  5 65 ];
```

The second array B is:

```
[ 1 26;
  31 56;
  4 121;
  5 54 ];
```

I want to obtain the final array C as following:

```
[ 1 21 26;
  4 12 121;
  5 65 54];
```

i.e. use the common elements of first column from A and B to sieve out the rows I want to extract from arrays A and B and generate C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the two-output vesion of [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[ii jj] = ismember(A(:,1), B(:,1));
C = [ A(ii,:) B(jj(ii),2) ];
```

Note that in the second line `ii` is a logical [index](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), whereas `jj(ii)` is a standard (integer) index.

Comment: Congratz Luis! Your 1000th answer!

Answer (score 2):

**[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** approach -

```
%// Slightly bigger and not-so-straightforward example to avoid any confusion
    A =[ 1 21;
    3 4;
    4 12;
    8 10
    5 65]

B = [ 1 26;
    31 56;
    4 121;
    5 54
    9 99
    8 88]

binmat = bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),B(:,1).');%//'
[v1,v2] = max(binmat,[],2);
C = [A(any(binmat,2),:) B(nonzeros(v1.*v2),2:end)]
```

Output -

```
A =
     1    21
     3     4
     4    12
     8    10
     5    65

B =
     1    26
    31    56
     4   121
     5    54
     9    99
     8    88


C =
     1    21    26
     4    12   121
     8    10    88
     5    65    54
```

Comment: Our approaches give different results if for example the last two rows of `B` are interchanged. The OP should have clarified. But from the wording, it would appear order doesn't matter?

Comment: ... Or perhaps you are missing a `.'` within `bsxfun`?

Comment: yeah that might be it! Thanks! My system running slow, I have like 30 something tabs open! And now I need to do some more processing.

Comment: I think you then need an `any` (because `ind` is now a column): `C = [A(any(ind),:) B(...,2:end)]`. And to index into `B` you may also need some changes; `any(ind)` may not work

Comment: Yeah turned out a bit of extra code, but not too bad in the end I think.

Comment: The party wouldn't be he same without `bsxfun`:-)